# get all posts json format in wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress

I am trying to fetch all posts as follows:

```
http://myexample.com/wp-json/posts
```

but not all of the results are fetched.I tried adding `?numberposts=-1` to the url so I can fetch all of them but still nothing happened.
Concerning the Settings->Reading, it's set to 4 because that's what should appear in the website so I don't wish to change it.

Any ideas how I can proceed?

Comment: you used some plugin?

Comment: just the json api one

Comment: I don't know how do this using an API. But if you want create a webservice using php and JSON, I can help. So, you need understand about database of the wordpress.

Comment: I understand wordpress database but I couldn't fetch all of my data. It usually fetches only the number sepecified in the Settings=>Reading part in admin page.I changed that to 999999 so I can gurantee to fetch all results.